# Admob Banner ads not taking full width in landscape

Tags: android

I am setting Banner ads programatically in my app and the code works good but I realised that in Landscape mode the banner ad doesn't fit the width of the screen . Is that normal thing ? or there is something wrong with my code ?

Please find bellow the code and XML File

```
        View adContainer = findViewById(R.id.adMobView);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) adContainer.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        adContainer.setLayoutParams(lp);
        AdView mAdView = new AdView(getApplicationContext());
        /// Set AdSize
        AdSize adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        double density = dm.density * 160;
        double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
        if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
            adSize = AdSize.LEADERBOARD;
        } else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
            adSize = AdSize.MEDIUM_RECTANGLE;
        } else { // > 320 X 50
            adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        }

        mAdView.setAdSize(adSize);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(unit_id);
        ((RelativeLayout) adContainer).addView(mAdView);
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("892C1ABF3CEB327D810DB65D4F22C17E").build();
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

XML

> ```
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/adMobView"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below:-

```
((RelativeLayout) adContainer).addView(mAdView,  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```